# Format <code> from Contentful Rich-Text field

Tags: gatsby, rtf, contentful

I'm building my portfolio and I would like to show some code-snippets within my paragraphs. Unfortunately, the code gets displayed without any line breaks and it just looks very unprofessional.

I am using the rich-text-react-renderer and I tried to add the option below to convert "/n" into br-tags ([documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer)). I am assuming it might not work because code is not really text? Any input is much appreciated!

```
const options = {
        renderNode: {
            "embedded-asset-block": (node) => {
                const alt = node.data.target.fields.title["en-US"]
                const url = node.data.target.fields.file['en-US'].url
                return <img alt={alt} src={url}/>
            }
        },
        renderText: text => { return text.split('/n').reduce((children, textSegment, index) => {
            return [...children, index > 0 && <br key={index}/>, textSegment];
        })}
    }
```

Comment: hey, did you find the solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I decided to use screenshots instead :(